# python regex to find "cat" but not "catfish" or "caterpillar", etc

Tags: python, regex

I'm not very used with regex and I'm having trouble creating one that would find "cat" anywhere in a string followed (or not) by any punctuations but not "caterpillar", "catfish", etc.

Comment: use word boundaries `r'\bcat\b'`

Comment: Read [**paragraph one and two**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python regular expressions, `\b` is a word boundary so you can search for `cat\b` (though that will also pick up things like `bobcat` or `tomcat` so you may need to use `\bcat\b` if you don't want those).

From the [Python 3.4 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) (though 2.7 is [very similar](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html)):

> **\b** - Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.
>
> A word is defined as a sequence of Unicode alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore Unicode character.
>
> Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string. This means that r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'.
>
> By default Unicode alphanumerics are the ones used, but this can be changed by using the ASCII flag. Inside a character range, \b represents the backspace character, for compatibility with Python’s string literals.